# Debugging python in Atom?

Tags: python, debugging, atom-editor

Any package or IDE for Atom that will allow me to watch variables when debugging?

I tried https://github.com/webBoxio/atom-hashrocket
but this does not let me go step by step

I tried https://atom.io/packages/python-debugger
But it has no watched variables.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 13):

The best debugger I've been able to find for Atom is this: https://atom.io/packages/python-debugger, but it doesn't (from what I can tell) allow you to watch variables. You can step through code and type in the name of the variable you're trying to observe and the plugin will print the variable's value to the console. I think it's just a fancy UI for the `pdb` debugger tool in Python. If you want an actual debugger for Python and you don't mind using a different text editor, you could try VSCode: https://code.visualstudio.com/ and download the python debugger plugin, which lets you watch variables and set breakpoints much like Visual Studio or XCode, or you could try the community version of PyCharm: https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/ which has a debugger built in.

Comment: Thank you, the answer helped me. But is there still no better solution for atom? With seeing variables, history of commands while in debugging mode, etc.?

Comment: Atom, in the debugger view, says "No debuggers installed", even though I have installed python-debugger.

Answer (score 10):

Try [atom-ide-debugger-python](https://atom.io/packages/atom-ide-debugger-python).  It runs with atom's [ide-python](https://atom.io/packages/ide-python) and allows variable watching as well as breakpoint setting.

Edit 2020-09: since facebook abandoned the atom-ide project, atom-ide-debugger-python has been unmaintained.

Comment: amazing! This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: Its GitHub is currently archived and it's not showing up in the debugger list for me after installing it. Is there anywhere you can still get support for this package? Might be interesting to add that to your answer.

Comment: @RobinDeSchepper, I've noted the maintenance status of the project.  Unfortunately, I don't know about any continued support for atom-ide-debugger-python since I've been using VSCode recently.  Quick searching didn't yield any leads.  If you find anything, please let me know!