# Python script throws no errors when it should

Tags: python, nested-loops, http-proxy, praw

I have written the following code and it works flawlessly but at one moment it starts typing out "programm ootab 3 minutit" after every 3 minutes. It means.. it skips all the print commands in between in the loops without throwing ANY errors. I have no idea how it can behave like that and it happens at random.. not during a specific loop or anything.

```
import praw
from time import sleep
import requests
from csv import DictReader
import os


#rotating proxy, 3 min, public proxies
os.environ["HTTPS_PROXY"] = "http://xxx.xxx.255.118:xxxxx"
os.environ["HTTP_PROXY"] = "http://xxx.xxx.255.118:xxxxx"

nr = 0
kommi_nr = 0


with open('file.csv', 'r') as read_obj:
    csv_dict_reader = DictReader(read_obj)
    for row in csv_dict_reader:

        #connection with api
        platform = praw.Platform(
            client_id = row['client_id'],
            client_secret = row['client_secret'],
            user_agent = row['username'],
            username = row['username'],
            password = row['password'],
            ratelimit_seconds = 930,
        )


        
        with open("posts.txt", 'a') as posted_comments:
            with open("source.txt", encoding="utf8") as subs:
                content = subs.readlines()

            for line in content:
                for post in platform.subplatform(content[nr].rstrip()).new(limit = 1):
                    if post.locked:
                        nr += 1
                        comment_done = False
                    else:
                        with open("spinned_comments.txt") as spinned_comments:
                            kindel_kommi_rida = spinned_comments.readlines()
                            post.reply(kindel_kommi_rida[kommi_nr])
                            print(row['username'] + " posted to " + post.permalink + " from IP: " + requests.get("https://icanhazip.com", timeout=1.5).text.strip())
                            print("KOMMENTAAR: " + kindel_kommi_rida[kommi_nr])
                            posted_comments.write(row['username'] + "\n")
                            kommi_nr +=1
                            nr += 1
                            comment_done = True
                if comment_done:
                    break
        print("programm ootab 3 minutit")
        sleep(180)
```

Comment: Did you step through this line-by-line in a debugger? That's the first step to solving any issue like this. Also, the line `posted_comments.write("row['username'] + "\n")` has an unclosed quotation mark.

Comment: Yeah, that is a typo when I quickly tried to replace sensitive info when posting it here. I will edit my original post. How do I step it through by debugger? I use ATOM IDE + some module that makes it run also.. srry.. this is my first project

Comment: I'm not familiar with ATOM but [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41539235/debugging-python-in-atom) is a post about debugging in it. As an alternative, PyCharm is free and has an excellent built-in debugger, [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/debugging-your-first-python-application.html) is info about how to use it.